# How to run a for loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to run a help function by all element from a list as the parameter

```
-- Help Function
helpFun :: Int -> Int -> Int
helpFun x y = x + y

-- Main Function
mainfun :: [Int] -> [Int]
mainfun x = helpfun 2 [j | j <- x]
```

If we assume x is a list of int `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
what should I change to make it run `helpFun` for all element in the list? 
I want to get all number from `helpFun 2 0` to `helpFun 2 6`

so just something like

```
for a in list:
    tt = helpFun 2 a
    return tt
```

Comment: You might want to read up on some haskell literature. http://learnyouahaskell.com/ is a nice place to start

Answer (score 10):

There's no such a thing as a for loop in Haskell.

To apply a function to each element in a list, you can either use `map` or a list comprehension. Since you already have a list comprehension (which currently does not do anything), let's just use that:

```
mainfun xs = [helpfun 2 x | x <- xs]
```

The alternative using `map` would be:

```
mainfun xs = map (helpfun 2) xs
```